# $(a\otimes b)^z = a^z \otimes b^z$ for elements in a $C^*$-algebra and $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory, tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be unital $C^*$-algebras. Let $a\in A$ and $b \in B$ be positive and invertible elements, so that in particular we can use the continuous functional calculus to define $a^z$ and $b^z$ and $(a\otimes b)^z$ where $z\in \mathbb{C}$. I want to show that
$$(a\otimes b)^z = a^z\otimes b^z$$ as elements of the $C^*$-algebra $A\otimes B$ (say equiped with the minimal norm, but I don't think the choice of norm matters).

**Attempt**: Let $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$. Then clearly $(a\otimes b)^{1/n} = a^{1/n} \otimes b^{1/n}$ by uniqueness of the positive $n^{th}$ root of a positive element. Hence, $(a\otimes b)^{m/n}= (a^{1/n}\otimes b^{1/n})^m = a^{m/n}\otimes b^{m/n}$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$. Applying the same argument with $a$ replaced by $a^{-1}$ and $b$ by $b^{-1}$ yields $(a\otimes b)^q = a^q \otimes b^q$ for all $q\in \mathbb{Q}$. By density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and using the fact that $x \mapsto x^z$ is uniformly continuous on compacts, I can then deduce that $(a\otimes b)^r = a^r \otimes b^r$ for all $r\in \mathbb{R}$.

How can I deduce that the equality holds for all complex numbers? Perhaps we must prove that
$$z \mapsto (a\otimes b)^z, \quad z \mapsto a^z \otimes b^z$$
are analytic functions $\mathbb{C}\to A\otimes B$ that agree on $\mathbb{R}$, so that they agree everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument with the analytic functions probably works, but I'm usually scared of operator-valued analytic functions, so I will not go there.

On the other hand, you can do this kind of directly.

First, since $(a\otimes 1)^n=a^n\otimes 1$, we get that $p(a\otimes 1)=p(a)\otimes 1$ for any polynomial, and this forces
$$\tag1
f(a\otimes 1)=f(a)\otimes 1,\qquad f(1\otimes b)=1\otimes f(b)
$$
for any continuous function $f$.

Now, by definition,
\begin{align}\tag2
(a\otimes b)^z=e^{z\,\log(a\otimes b)}.
\end{align}
Note that, since $a\otimes 1$ and $1\otimes b $ commute, their logarithms commute and
$$\tag3
e^{\log (a\otimes 1) + \log(1\otimes b)}=e^{\log (a\otimes 1)}e^{\log(1\otimes b)}=(a\otimes 1)(1\otimes b)=a\otimes b. 
$$
Thus, as the exponential is injective on positive operators,
\begin{align}\tag4
\log (a\otimes 1)+\log (1\otimes b)=\log (a\otimes b).
\end{align}
Combining everything,
\begin{align}
(a\otimes b)^z&=e^{z\log(a\otimes b)}=e^{z(\log a \otimes 1)+z(1\otimes\log b)}=e^{z\log(a\otimes 1)}\,e^{z\log(1\otimes b)}\\[0.3cm]
&=(a\otimes 1)^z(1\otimes b)^z
=(a^z\otimes 1)(1\otimes b^z)=a^z\otimes b^z
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a fast way to see that the exponential is injective on positive operators?

Comment: Ah this probably follows from the corresponding fact for the complex numbers using an argument with functional calculus composition.

Comment: It's fairly direct. If $e^x=e^y$, they obviously commute so you get $e^{x-y}=1$. This reduces the problem to the case $e^x=1$ with $x$ selfadjoint. But then $\lambda\in\sigma(x)$ is real and satisfies $e^\lambda=1$; that is, $\lambda=0$. Then $x=0$.

Comment: Am I right if I say that you are using that functional calculus is injective? I.e. $e^x = 1$ implies $\exp = 1$ as functions on $\sigma(x)$, which forces the spectrum of $x$ to be trivial so $x=0$?

Comment: Being that the exponential has an explicit series, I think it's  doable without functional calculus. But yes, the usual argument is to go via the Spectral Mapping Theorem, which uses either functional calculus or the Spectral Theorem.